# magento - include core functionality in custom module

Tags: magento

I've recently made my first couple of simple modules for magento. Basically just trying out making a module that printed 'hi'. Then one that included the site design, and finally one that inserted it's own block into the content area to print some stuff.

Now, what I really want with this module is to be able to list products (using the same layout as normal product listing) but based on ID's. Like from cookies or as an example, static array of product ID's.

How would I go about to reuse the product listing code as much as possible and retaining the theming for it?  Also if there is some small detail I wanted to change in the layout - how could i make a small template adjustment on the fly/programmatically?

Is this even the right way to go about it, to create a new module and somehow include existing functionality in it?  Or should I just try to recreate the product listing and mimic the design?

Lots of questions I know, but it's hard to find relevant information beyond the very simplest modules. TIA.

Comment: You may want to take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/72319/ and the way they reuse the list.phtml to display random products. You could write  your custom logic to search for the products to display in _getProductCollection()

Comment: Ok thanks but at first glanse it looks like that's code specific to inclusion in a CMS page and not for module development. Maybe it contains information that can be used for both, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: In your custom module (layout.xml) /app/design/frontend/default/ThemeName/layout/CustomModuleName.xml you could do something like <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="list_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"></block>
        </reference>

Comment: that worked fine, so thanks for a great starting point :)